# How to deal apostrophe in JSON from webservice?

Tags: ios, json, string, swift3

I'm using NSURLSession to communicate with a Webservice. However, in the JSON from Webservice I'm getting strings like this Biblotecas de cat& aacute;logos de Marcas i.e. Biblotecas de catálogos de Marcas. I need to get rid of the text cat& aacute;logos and get the original string. How can i do this.
I'm using this code for parsing the JSON.

```
guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] else{

                self.showalertview(messagestring: parseError)
                return
            }
```

Comment: Can I see your sample response?

Comment: @anilkukdeja {
    data =     (
                {
            description = "Biblotecas de cat&aacute;logos de Marcas";
            name = "Biblotecas de cat&aacute;logos de Marcas";
        }
    );
    msg = u00e9xito;
    result = 1;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to ask the owner of the webservice to send UTF-8 compliant text.

If this is not possible `NSAttributedString` can decode HTML entities in a very convenient way, this is a `String` extension adding the computed property `htmlDecoded`. As the conversion can fail for several reasons the return value is an optional:

```
extension String {
    var htmlDecoded : String? {
        guard let encodedString = self.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        let options : [String:Any] = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue]
        return  try? NSAttributedString(data: encodedString, options: options, documentAttributes: nil).string
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
let string = "Biblotecas de cat&aacute;logos de Marcas"
print(string.htmlDecoded) // "Biblotecas de catálogos de Marcas"
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this code.

Comment: you saved my day..! Thanks.